# Ethers js estimate gas offline?

Tags: javascript, gas-price, ethers.js

[Looking here](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-wallet.html#blockchain-operations) in the docs it mentions I need to have the provider attached to estimate gas. But for formatting a transaction offline, I dont have access to the provider. Is there a way to estimate the gas when you dont have access to the provider? I tried sending the transaction without `gasPrice` and it worked... however, should I provide this price in my formatted offline transaction? Here is how I am formatting my transaction without provider:

```
const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(abi);
const func = iface.functions.setValues.encode([name, value]);
const nonce = await NonceManager.requestNonce(wallet);
const txs = {
  gasLimit: 1000001,
  data: func,
  to: address,
  nonce: nonce,
}
const iSign = await wallet.sign(txs);
```

The `iSign` is my transaction to send when needed. But is there a way to estimate gase without provider?

Answer (score 0):

[image: https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-contract.html]

see details from the documentations of etherjs v4
https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-contract.html